# SP2010, CQWP showing <a> on title field

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have the following line CQWP in itemstyle.xsl:

```
xsl:value-of select="@Title"
```

now i want a hyper link on **title** to navigate on my list item on from this CQWP.
please help me.

I am using Custom List.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}"><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></a>
```